# Webpack Can't Load Modules ... When "type":""module"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, es6-modules

I'm trying to build a project with Webpack 5.74.0 (after installing it globally):

```
webpack --config src/webpack.config.js
```

My `src/webpack.config.js` file uses `import` syntax, eg:

```
import ReactRefreshPlugin from '@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin';
```

But that should be fine because I have:

```
"type": "module"
```

in the project's `package.json`.  However, despite that, when I run Webpack I get:

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/home/me/project/src/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] /home/me/project/src/webpack.config.js:1
import ReactRefreshPlugin from '@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at WebpackCLI.tryRequireThenImport (/home/me/project/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:204:22)
    at loadConfigByPath (/home/me/project/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1404:38)
```

I understand that I can use loaders to enable `import` syntax *in the project I'm building* ... but how can I fix Webpack to read the config file, if it ignores my  `package.json`?

**EDIT:** I found a workaround: if I rename `webpack.config.js` => `webpack.config.mjs` (ie. I force it to recognize the file as an ES Module file) everything works.

But, it still doesn't answer why Webpack ignores `"type": "module"` in my `package.json`, so I'm leaving the question open in hopes of understanding that.